# Doubling the image count

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

When I use `keras` for CNN, the number of images is getting doubled.
[output from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrrWr.png)

The original number of images is 8000.
But, it is doubling the count.
The same happens with test_set.

I have used the code from keras documentation itself. (`.flow_from_directory()`)

Here's the code:

```py
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set', 
target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 16, class_mode = 'binary')
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you're referring to? Give a code example.

Comment: `training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 16,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')`

Comment: I've amended your question to add the coding example please help the community to help you.. add more detail to the example be more clear otherwise you're not going to get good answers. I still feel like there's a lot of code missing here.

Comment: Could there be 8000 images for each class totalling 16,000? I feel like 8000 is a rather small dataset.

Comment: No, there is a total of 10000 images. 5000 for cats and 5000 for dogs. 8000 correspond to the training set. But I get 16000.